# GraphQL mutation variables with objects

Tags: ecmascript-6, graph, graphql, mutation

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
export const CREATE_BUSINESS = gql`
    mutation createBusinessMutation(
        $name: String!
        $website: String!
        $streetAddress: String!
        $city: String!
        $countryCode: String!
        $postCode: String!
    ) {
        business(
            input: {
                name: $name
                number: $number
                website: $website 
                address: {
                    streetAddress: $streetAddress
                    city: $city
                    countryCode: $countryCode
                    postCode: $postCode
                }
            }
        ) {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;
```

and I'm having this error:

```
1: {message: "Variable "$streetAddress" of required type "[String]!" was not provided.",…}
2: {message: "Variable "$city" of required type "[String]!" was not provided.",…}
3: {message: "Variable "$countryCode" of required type "[String]!" was not provided.",…}
4: {message: "Variable "$postCode" of required type "[String]!" was not provided.",…}
```

I'm only having this issue when I nest as an object otherwise it works.

Any help?

Comment: Well, *did* you provide values for the variables when calling the mutation?

Comment: Btw, it would be much simpler to have a single `$input` variable in your mutation, and just pass an object for it.